# Swift Property that conforms to a Protocol and Class

Tags: ios, swift, generics, properties, protocols

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate> *thing;
```

I want to implement a property like in this Objective-C code in Swift. So here is what I've tried:

```
class AClass<T: UIViewController where T: UITableViewDelegate>: UIViewController {
    var thing: T!
}
```

This compiles. My problem comes when I add properties from the storyboard. The `@IBOutlet` tag generates an compiler error.

```
class AClass<T: UIViewController where T: UITableViewDelegate>: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var anotherThing: UILabel!  // error
    var thing: T!
}
```

The error:

```
Variable in a generic class cannot be represented in Objective-C
```

Am I implementing this right? What can I do to fix or get around this error?

**EDIT:**

Swift 4 finally has a solution for this problem. See my updated answer.

Comment: I was looking to do this a couple months ago & the consensus at the time was that it wasn't possible. I'd love it if that were incorrect though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update for Swift 4**

Swift 4 has added support for representing a type as a class that conforms to a protocol. The syntax is `Class & Protocol`. Here is some example code using this concept from "What's New in Swift" (session 402 from WWDC 2017):

```
protocol Shakeable {
    func shake()
}
extension UIButton: Shakeable { /* ... */ }
extension UISlider: Shakeable { /* ... */ }

// Example function to generically shake some control elements
func shakeEm(controls: [UIControl & Shakeable]) {
    for control in controls where control.isEnabled {
        control.shake()
    }
}
```

As of Swift 3, this method causes problems because you can't pass in the correct types. If you try to pass in `[UIControl]`, it doesn't have the `shake` method. If you try to pass in `[UIButton]`, then the code compiles, but you can't pass in any `UISlider`s. If you pass in `[Shakeable]`, then you can't check `control.state`, because `Shakeable` doesn't have that. Swift 4 finally addressed the topic.

**Old Answer**

I am getting around this problem for the time being with the following code:

```
// This class is used to replace the UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate> 
// declaration in Objective-C
class ConformingClass: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {}

class AClass: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var anotherThing: UILabel!
    var thing: ConformingClass!
}
```

This seems hackish to me. If any of the delegate methods were required, then I would have to implement those methods in `ConformingClass` (which I do NOT want to do) and override them in a subclass.

I have posted this answer in case anyone else comes across this problem and my solution helps them, but I am not happy with the solution. If anyone posts a better solution, I will accept their answer.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong; subclasses of the class in `[Myclass & Myprotocol]` are brutally denied.

Comment: I used it as the type of a property. I'm not sure, maybe the syntax was incorrect. Looking at the WWDC video now at around 6:44 the syntax for a property is `var client: (Someclass & Protocol)`

Comment: I was having type errors with `[Myclass & Myprotocol]` but `(Myclass & Myprotocol)` works for me

Answer (score 7):

It's not the ideal solution, but you can use a generic function instead of a generic class, like this:

```
class AClass: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var anotherThing: UILabel!
  private var thing: UIViewController?

  func setThing<T: UIViewController where T: UITableViewDelegate>(delegate: T) {
    thing = delegate
  }
}
```

Comment: The biggest thing I want is to be able to call one of the class or delegate methods from the property. For example, if `thing` is a `UIViewController` that implements `UITableViewDelegate`, I want to be able to access `thing.navigationController` AND `thing.didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` without having to cast `thing` when I make the call. Did that make sense?

Comment: so this can be done for functions, but NOT for properties? Annoying.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same issue, and also tried the generic approach. Eventually the generic approach broke the entire design.

After re-thinking about this issue, I found that a protocol which cannot be used to fully specify a type (in other words, must come with additional type information such as a class type) is unlikely to be a complete one. Moreover, although the Objc style of declaring `ClassType<ProtocolType>` comes handy, it disregards the benefit of abstraction provided by protocol because such protocol does not really raise the abstraction level. Further, if such declaration appears at multiple places, it has to be duplicated. Even worse, if multiple declarations of such type are interrelated (possibly a single object will be passed around them ), the programme becomes fragile and hard to maintain because later if the declaration at one place needs to be changed, all the related declarations have to be changed as well.

**Solution**

If the use case of a property involves both a protocol (say `ProtocolX`) and some aspects of a class (say `ClassX`), the following approach could be taken into account:

1. Declare an additional protocol that inherits from `ProtocolX` with the added method/property requirements which `ClassX` automatically satisfy. Like the example below, a method and a property are the additional requirements, both of which `UIViewController` automatically satisfy.

   ```
   protocol CustomTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {
       var navigationController: UINavigationController? { get }
       func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: AnyObject?)
   }
   ```
2. Declare an additional protocol that inherits from `ProtocolX` with an additional read-only property of the type `ClassX`. Not only does this approach allow the use of `ClassX` in its entirety, but also exhibits the flexibility of not requiring an implementation to subclass `ClassX`. For example:

   ```
   protocol CustomTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {
       var viewController: UIViewController { get }
   }

   // Implementation A
   class CustomViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

       var viewController: UIViewController { return self }

       ... // Other important implementation
   }

   // Implementation B
   class CustomClass: UITableViewDelegate {

       private var _aViewControllerRef: UIViewController // Could come from anywhere e.g. initializer
       var viewController: UIViewController { return _aViewControllerRef } 

       ... // UITableViewDelegate methods implementation
   }
   ```

*PS.* The snippet above are for demonstration only, mixing `UIViewController` and `UITableViewDelegate` together is not recommended.

**Edit for Swift 2+:** Thanks for @Shaps's comment, the following could be added to save having to implement the desired property everywhere.

```
extension CustomTableViewDelegate where Self: UIViewController { 
    var viewController: UIViewController { return self } 
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer I have seen so far on the topic. I think your thoughts on losing the benefits of abstraction are well put. The more I think about it, I was trying write Objective-C code in a Swift syntax, which was the real source of the problem. Thanks for the in-depth answer!

Comment: Though I agree with your comments 100% in principle, it doesn't help when we're working with Cocoa classes of which we have no control.  If a UIKit method requires a parameter to be of type UIViewController and I'm being a good POP programmer and require a protocol for my added functionality, there is no way around it.  I need an object that satisfies a protocol and super class requirement.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Works perfectly for my problem. One addition I added was 

`extension CustomTableViewDelegate where Self: UIViewController {
  var viewController: UIViewController { return self }
}`

Saves having to implement the var everywhere :)

Comment: Thanks @Shaps for your addition. This answer was posted in swift 1.x era. I will add your information to it.

Comment: About the "Edit for Swift 2+", should the property viewController be declared weak to avoid retain cycles?

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a delegate in Swift like this:

```
weak var delegate : UITableViewDelegate?
```

It will work with even hybrid(Objective-c and swift) project. Delegate should be optional & weak because its availability is not guaranteed and weak does not create retain cycle.

You are getting that error because there are no generics in Objective-C and it will not allow you to add @IBOutlet property.

**Edit: 1. Forcing a type on delegate**

To force that delegate is always a UIViewController you can implement the custom setter and throw exception when its not a UIViewController.

```
weak var _delegate : UITableViewDelegate? //stored property
var delegate : UITableViewDelegate? {
    set {
        if newValue! is UIViewController {
            _delegate = newValue
        } else {
            NSException(name: "Inavlid delegate type", reason: "Delegate must be a UIViewController", userInfo: nil).raise()
        }
    }
    get {
        return _delegate
    }
}
```

Comment: But if I only declare it as a `UITableViewDelegate`, then I lose the other requirement of being a `UIViewController`. I want to declare that the property is a `UIViewController` that conforms to `UITableViewDelegate`.

Comment: you can do that by defining custom setter method for delegate. When delegate is not a view controller you can throw an exception `[NSException raise:@"Invalid foo value" format:@"foo of %d is invalid", foo];`

Comment: I would miss out on method calls that I could make with a `UIViewController`. If it is just of type `UITableViewDelegate`, then I can't call `self.delegate.dismissViewControllerAnimated()`, even though it will be a `UIViewController`.

Comment: Added the code to force the type check. If its fix your issue then accept and up vote this answer.