# Storing UIViewController generic with a protocol as a property

Tags: ios, swift, generics, properties

Okay, so I'm pretty sure I'm overthinking this.

I am passing through a `viewController` that conforms to a protocol as a generic like so:

```
static func sortPage<T: UIViewController>(controller: T, err: NSError) where T: SortAlertDelegate { }
```

What I want to be able to do is store that `controller`as a property so I can access all the functions `UIViewController` gives me and the functions thats the `SortAlerDelegate` gives me.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift Property that conforms to a Protocol and Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30495828/swift-property-that-conforms-to-a-protocol-and-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not possible unless you move the generic constraint on top of your class definition like:

```
class ViewController<T: UIViewController> : UIViewController where T: SortAlertDelegate { 
     let delegateController: T
}
```

But you can also make two references in your class like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController { 
     let controller: UIViewController
     let delegate: SearchAlertDelegate
}
```

And then store the same object as two different references.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a type *and* protocol conformance for a property. You'll need to cast your property to the correct type whenever you want to use specific features. However, you can make this less painful with a bit of boilerplate:

```
let myProperty: UIViewController? = nil {
    willSet(newValue) {
        if (newValue as? SortAlertDelegate != nil) {
            myProperty = newValue
        } else {
            myProperty = nil
        }
    }
}
```

This way, if you try to set the property to an object which doesn't conform to the protocol, the set will be aborted and the property will be set to `nil`.

You can also write read-only properties in order to get your property as the type you need at the moment:

```
let myPropertyAsViewController: UIViewController? {
    get { return myProperty }
}

let myPropertyAsDelegate: SortAlertDelegate? {
    get {
        if let myProperty = myProperty {
            return myProperty as! SortAlertDelegate
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```